# How to remove an observer from livedata so it doesn't show twice when navigating back to the fragment

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, mediatorlivedata

I have a fragment which displays a popup when the user is successfully logged in. If I navigate to a new fragment and come back, the popup with the previous username is shown again. I fixed this problem using SingleLiveEvent, but I now have to refactor my code to use MediatorLiveData as my data can come from 2 sources (remote and database), and it is not compatible with SingleLiveEvent.

I tried using an event wrapper and removing observers on onDestroyView() but so far nothing is working, the livedata onChanged function keeps getting called when I move back to the fragment. Here is some of my fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    binding.setLifecycleOwner(getActivity());

    //Get the attendanceViewModel for registering attendance
    attendanceViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AttendanceViewModel.class);
    attendanceViewModel.getAttendance().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), attendanceAndMember -> {
        if (attendanceAndMember != null && attendanceAndMember instanceof AttendanceMemberModel) {
            clokedInOutMember = attendanceAndMember.member;
        }
        showResultClockInOutPopup();
    });

    return binding.getRoot();
}

private void showResultClockInOutPopup() {

    clockInBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.status_clock_in_out_popup, null);
    TextView responseClockInOut = view.findViewById(R.id.responseClockInOut);
    Button dismissButton = view.findViewById(R.id.dismissButton);

    //Setup Popup Text
    if (clokedInOutMember != null) {
        if (StringToBool(clokedInOutMember.is_clocked_in_temp)) {
            responseClockInOut.setText("Bienvenue " + clokedInOutMember.name + ", tu es bien enregistré(e).");
        } else {
            responseClockInOut.setText("Désolé de te voir partir " + clokedInOutMember.name + ", à bientôt!");
        }
    } else {
        responseClockInOut.setText("Oups, il semblerait qu'il y ait une erreur...\n Essaye à nouveau.");
    }

    [..SETUP ALERTDIALOG...]

        //Dismiss popup
        dismissButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            clockInResultDialog.dismiss();
            clockInResultPopupShowed = false;
            clokedInOutMember = null;
        });

        clockInResultDialog.show();
        clockInResultPopupShowed = true;
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    attendanceViewModel.getAttendance().removeObservers(this);
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

And here is my ViewModel, I have to use transformations as I am getting the userId from the fragment, passing to the Viewmodel which passes it to the repository for query (maybe there is a better way?):

```
public class AttendanceViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private AttendanceRepository repository = AttendanceRepository.getInstance();
public LiveData<AttendanceMemberModel> mAttendanceAndMember;
private MutableLiveData<String> mId =  new MutableLiveData<>();

private MediatorLiveData<AttendanceMemberModel> mObservableAttendance = new MediatorLiveData<AttendanceMemberModel>();
{
    mObservableAttendance.setValue(null);

    mAttendanceAndMember = Transformations.switchMap(mId, id -> {
        return repository.saveAttendance(id);
    });

    mObservableAttendance.addSource(mAttendanceAndMember, mObservableAttendance::setValue);
}


public AttendanceViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
}

public LiveData<AttendanceMemberModel> getAttendance() {
    return mObservableAttendance;

}

public void setMemberId(String id) {
    mId.setValue(id);
}


@Override
protected void onCleared() {
    mObservableAttendance.setValue(null);
    super.onCleared();
}
}
```

Comment: Your old Observer is being correctly removed, that isn't your problem. LiveData is for **state**, not for events, so your new Observer is just getting the last state when it starts observing. That's how LiveData works.

Comment: So setting the livedata to null onDestroyView would be the way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you two ways. First create a `boolean` variable whether dialog is shown in `Fragment` and after showing dialog set it to `true` and before showing dialog check if dialog is shown. Second way is after showing dialog set `livedata` value to null and check if observer value null before showing dialog. I prefer second way.

Comment: I tried the second way (setting livedata to null and adding a livedata boolean isReset that I observe before showing the dialog, I need it because I show another popup if livedata is null) and it's working, thank you! I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but if not I will set it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I gave you logic and implementation upon you. I can't suggest better way right now.

Answer (score 1):

Use anyone of them, which works and behaves according to your need.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    attendanceViewModel.getAttendance().removeObservers(this);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    attendanceViewModel.getAttendance().removeObservers(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

[Fragment Life Cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Lifecycle)

Have a look at the lifecycle of the fragment, it will give you bit more idea.
Let me know if this works or not.

Comment: I tried that, moving the removeObservers() through all the chain until I put in in onDestroyView, none of them are working

Comment: same here.. it's not working for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to the same is to bind your view model in OnViewCreated meathod.

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        attendanceViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AttendanceViewModel.class);
        setUpObservers();
      }



    private void setUpObservers() {
        attendanceViewModel.getAttendance().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), attendanceAndMember -> {
        if (attendanceAndMember != null && attendanceAndMember instanceof AttendanceMemberModel) {
            clokedInOutMember = attendanceAndMember.member;
        }
        showResultClockInOutPopup();
    });
    }
```

If still it don't work kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Try onActivityCreated insted of onViewCreated!

Comment: @Bek In your android studio, create a new Fragment with viewModel and all your doubts may get cleared over there it self.

Comment: @Vera you might consider using CompositeDisposable into your view model to dispose the observer.

Comment: The problem is you start observing on  `onViewCreated` or `onActivityCreated` and when return that fragment `onViewCreated` or `onActivityCreated` called again. She is removing observers `onDestroyView` but when returning to that fragment, starts observing again and gets last state of viewmodel. That's why your code doesn't work.

Comment: @Vera Comment all your code in onDestroyView, as LiveData is already lifeCycle aware and please post your whole view model class.